# CSS oblique div few deg with background image

Tags: html, css

I created 3 div's with each 33% width, that I want to oblique a few degrees.
The first and last div should not get a oblique, so that it will only work for the inner content. This also because I want to add 4 divs (25% width) in the near future.

I also want to make a the div with background wider, on hover. So that other divs will become 30% and the one on hover will become 40%.

*Note: I do not want to rotate the image itself, only the div. The image should be place without rotation.*

I can not get it done with CSS.

My current code:

```
<div class="divisions">

<div class="col-sm-4 division hosting">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 division shop">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 division solutions">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cwxLw7h/2/

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {margin: 0px;}

.divisions .col-xs-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
.divisions .division {
  transition: width 0.25s linear;
}
.divisions:hover .division {
  width: 31%;
}
.divisions:hover .division:hover {
  width: 38%;
}
.divisions .solutions .inner {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 750px;
  background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/f3ed524eaf11c7095fc583390eb346be/tumblr_oaj4d1Uh0n1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.divisions .shop .inner {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 750px;
  background: url(http://65.media.tumblr.com/8b638bda48df96a5350d7dd3796e459c/tumblr_oaj43tSwts1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.divisions .hosting .inner-holder {
  transform: skewX(-4deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 -30px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.divisions .hosting .inner {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 750px;
  background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/43a177556b301a8dc5cb45145050853b/tumblr_oaj40xITvh1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: skewX(4deg);
  margin: 0 -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="divisions">

  <div class="col-xs-4 division solutions">
    <div class="inner">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 division hosting">
    <div class="inner-holder">
      <div class="inner">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 division shop">
    <div class="inner">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does also rotate the image. I do not want to rotate the image. How can I only make the div oblique, but do not turn the image? And how can I create the hover effect?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The only thing I still miss, is the hover effect. When hovering on one of the 3 divs, that it will make that div larger on hover (40% width)

Comment: @HenkZ You are using Bootstrap's columns they have predefined widths for each column. Its better to not change them. If it is very necessary then better use columns without Bootstrap's classes.

Comment: Ok, I can use them without the Bootstrap's columns. But in that case, how can I change the width on hover?

Comment: @HenkZ here is a possible variant. you can play with it https://jsfiddle.net/1cwxLw7h/12/

Comment: Thanks! But that does infact all 3 divs. I want to use something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1cwxLw7h/13/. But how can I achieve that for the other div's, because sibling combinator does not work back up.

Comment: @HenkZ You can't select previous sibling with css. You need to take help from jQuery.

Comment: That's what I thought. Can you help me on the right jQuery code for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I need.

Comment: @HenkZ Sorry, I'm not sure about `jQuery.noConflict()`. You may ask another question for this. I hope you will get authentic answer from more experienced developers.

Comment: You can achieve this without the need for any JavaScript by simply changing the `.divisions:hover .division.hover` selector to `.divisions:hover .division:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code, it increase the `div size` when your hover on them.

```css
body {margin: 0px;}

.col-sm-4 {float: left; width: 33.33333333333333%; display: inline-block}
.divisions .solutions .inner {height: 100%; min-height: 750px; background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/f3ed524eaf11c7095fc583390eb346be/tumblr_oaj4d1Uh0n1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover}

.divisions .shop .inner {height: 100%; min-height: 750px; background: url(http://65.media.tumblr.com/8b638bda48df96a5350d7dd3796e459c/tumblr_oaj43tSwts1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover}

.divisions .hosting .inner {height: 100%; min-height: 750px; background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/43a177556b301a8dc5cb45145050853b/tumblr_oaj40xITvh1teue7jo1_1280.jpg) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover}
.divisions{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.divisions .solutions{
  transform:skew(-3deg);
  float:left;
  margin-left:-18px;
  transition:width 1s ease;
}
.divisions .solutions:hover{
  width:40%;
}
.divisions .hosting{
  transform:skew(-3deg);
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width:45%;
 transition:width 1s ease;
 }
.divisions .hosting:hover{
  width:50%;
}
.divisions .shop{
  transform:skew(-3deg);
  float:right;
  margin-right:-18px;
  transition:width 1s ease;
}
.divisions .shop:hover{
  width:45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="divisions">

<div class="col-sm-4 division solutions">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 division hosting">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 division shop">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>

</div>
```